# Using Visual Format Language with iCarousel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, icarousel

I love using iCarousel in my swift projects but there is one thing that I could not manage to overcome; I want to use Visual language for layout of the views in my project but whenever I use visual formats for iCarousel, it does not work.

I noticed that the problem is `TopMenuCarousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false` attribute.

Whenever I disable this attribute, my visual format constraints are disabled for iCarousel, and whenever I enable it, the constraints works perfectly but my iCarousel wont scroll and stay still always.

Current code:

#

```
import UIKit
import iCarousel

class Step2_HomePage: UIViewController,iCarouselDelegate,iCarouselDataSource     {


let TopMenuCarouselCount = 5

    var TopMenuCarousel = iCarousel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Step2HomePage icinde")



    TopMenuCarousel = iCarousel(frame: CGRect())
    view.addSubview(TopMenuCarousel)
  //  TopMenuCarousel.clipsToBounds = true
    TopMenuCarousel.type = .Linear
    TopMenuCarousel.dataSource = self
    TopMenuCarousel.delegate = self






 let views = [ "TopMenuCarousel": TopMenuCarousel  ]

    // 2
    var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()



    let TopMenuCarouselTop = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "V:|-100-[TopMenuCarousel]",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += TopMenuCarouselTop

    let TopMenuCarouselHorizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-0-[TopMenuCarousel]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)
    allConstraints += TopMenuCarouselHorizontal



    TopMenuCarousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    print("carousel number")
    return TopMenuCarouselCount

}

func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    print("carousel view icinde")
    let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 , width: 20, height: 20))

    tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    return tempView
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not setting any height to your iCarousel object. Try changing your first Constraint to:

```
let TopMenuCarouselTop = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:|-100-[TopMenuCarousel(20)]",
    options: [],
    metrics: nil,
    views: views)
```

Here is a full modified version of your original code. I made the views larger (yours were 20x20), and added some color to make it easier to see what's going on.

```
import UIKit
import iCarousel

class Step2_HomePage: UIViewController,iCarouselDelegate,iCarouselDataSource {

    // array of colors to make it easy to see the individual Carousel views
    let arrayOfColors = [ UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.orangeColor(), UIColor.greenColor()]

    let TopMenuCarouselCount = 5

    var TopMenuCarousel = iCarousel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Step2HomePage icinde")

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        // initialize the TopMenuCarousel object
        TopMenuCarousel = iCarousel(frame: CGRect())

        // add TopMenuCarousel to the view
        view.addSubview(TopMenuCarousel)

        // if clipsToBounds == true, TopMenuCarousel subviews will be clipped to the TopMenuCarousel frame
        // default is false

        //      TopMenuCarousel.clipsToBounds = true

        TopMenuCarousel.type = .Linear
        TopMenuCarousel.dataSource = self
        TopMenuCarousel.delegate = self

        TopMenuCarousel.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

        let views = [ "TopMenuCarousel": TopMenuCarousel  ]

        var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        // position TopMenuCarousel 100 from the Top, with a Height of 200
        let TopMenuCarouselTop = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|-100-[TopMenuCarousel(200)]",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)

        allConstraints += TopMenuCarouselTop

        // set TopMenuCarousel to stretch the full Width of the view
        let TopMenuCarouselHorizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|-0-[TopMenuCarousel]-0-|",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)

        allConstraints += TopMenuCarouselHorizontal

        // this property *must* be set to false
        TopMenuCarousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)

    }

    func numberOfItemsInCarousel(carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
        print("carousel number \(TopMenuCarouselCount)")
        return TopMenuCarouselCount
    }

    func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        print("carousel view icinde", index)

        // create a 200 x 160 view to add to TopMenuCarousel
        let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 , width: 200, height: 160))

        // give it one of the colors
        tempView.backgroundColor =  arrayOfColors[index % arrayOfColors.count]

        return tempView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Everyone, 

Unfortuntely it did not work :( 

I did as you suggested but this time, the iCarousel view did not have the vertical height as declared in constaint.

The view appeared in the most left-up corner of the screen with our any "Vertical" adjustment.

What can be the reason ?  By the way I deleted, the following line :

`TopMenuCarousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false`

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a full example... `TopMenuCarousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` *must* be set to false for the added constraints to work.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints are created and activated but never added to the view, you should use:

```
view.addConstraints(allConstraints)
```

after

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(allConstraints)
```

Also as DonMag stated, there is no height constraint, this means that if the iCarousel view doesn't have a correct intrinsic size it won't be displayed and you should add an explicit height like the example DonMag wrote.

Comment: That used to be the case... From Apple's docs: `When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, use the NSLayoutConstraint class’s activateConstraints: method instead of calling the addConstraints: method directly. The activateConstraints: method automatically adds the constraints to the correct views.` https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622513-addconstraints

Comment: wow, I didn't know that. So the only problem should be the height as you said!

Comment: Hi Everyone, 

Unfortuntely it did not work :( 

I did as you suggested but this time, the iCarousel view did not have the vertical height as declared in constaint.

The view appeared in the most left-up corner of the screen with our any "Vertical" adjustment.

What can be the reason ?  By the way I deleted, the following line :

`TopMenuCarousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false`

Comment: You deleted the line that is required to allow your assigned constraints to work. Un-delete that line.

Comment: You are are THE BEST. Thank you very much. It worked :):)